# How can I reset the data in the UserDefaults SwiftUI for log out button still if i push the back button its coming in

Tags: swiftui, swift5, logout, userdefaults

```
NavigationLink("", destination: login(),isActive: $goWhenTrue)

Button (action: { print("Button Tapped")}, label: {
    
    Text("LogOut")
        .font(.headline)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .frame(width: 340, height: 50)
        .background(Color.blue)
        .clipShape(Capsule())
        .padding()
        .onTapGesture {
            self.goWhenTrue = true
            if ((UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Username") != "nil")) {
                UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "Username")
            }
        }
})
```

In this program, I am logging out from my app, I used a `NavigationLink` on the logout button and I cleared the data with `UserDefaults` as you can see above.
here when I click the back button, I'm again going back to the home page rather than hanging in my login page.
I want to delete the values from `UserDefaults` whenever I log out from the session.
Can anybody give me a solution to this problem?

Comment: still not working when i press back button its still going back

Comment: yes you can my email id is visakh4488@gmail.com